# Add only Data in Textbox that is not empty

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm creating an Inventory System which the user can add multiple `Products, Itemcode, Quantity.` I have `10 textbox` per columns. The user can input 10 items then save all together. But my problem is that when you leave the other textbox empty it will add also the empty value of that textbox. My question is how can I filter the textboxes that are not empty so that those will only be save on my database. Here's what I got now:

```
var rows = new[]
    {
    new {Item = txtItem.Text, Product = txtProduct.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem2.Text, Product = txtProduct2.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity2.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem3.Text, Product = txtProduct3.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity3.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem4.Text, Product = txtProduct4.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity4.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem5.Text, Product = txtProduct5.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity5.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem6.Text, Product = txtProduct6.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity6.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem7.Text, Product = txtProduct7.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity7.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem8.Text, Product = txtProduct8.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity8.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem9.Text, Product = txtProduct9.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity9.Text},
    new {Item = txtItem10.Text, Product = txtProduct10.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity10.Text}
    };
    foreach (var row in rows)
                {
    OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(
         @"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime) values (@ItemCode,@ProductName,@Quantity,@DateAndTime)");
         cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", row.Item);
         cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", row.Product);
         cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", row.Quantity.ToString());

         cmdInsert.Connection = con;
         cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm new on Programming so please be kind. Thank you guys.

**EDIT**

I tried to use while statement after the `foreach statement` but it seems that it still not working

```
while(row.Item != null && row.Product != null && row.Quantity != null)
```

**ANSWER**

I replace the above code to this code and works

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Product) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Quantity))
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to check the Item, Product and Quantity on String.IsNullOrEmpty() in your foreach - loop and if so skip this row from inserting.

Comment: please see the above edit @MarcelTheis

Comment: actually if you have strings, only checking null will not get all. you have to check IsNullOrEmpty() this is provided by the string class and don´t use a while, use an if statement --> only write to the db IF there is something in those values.

Comment: something like: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item.Trim() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Product.Trim() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Quantity.ToString()Trim())  { // insert into db }

Comment: Found the answer. Thanks for that

Comment: Kindly answer my question so that I can accept as an answer on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if the data is empty or not, before inserting it into the db: 
enter an if clause into your foreach loop that looks something like this

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item.Trim() &&     
 !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Product.Trim()) &&
 !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Quantity.ToString().Trim())) 
{ 
   // insert into db
}
```

With this you exclude the empty values from inserting.